# Uniqueness of system of ODE - invariant set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem which I am struggling to solve. It goes like:
$$
x^\prime = x- \frac{x^3}{3}-y\\
y^\prime = x - 1 -y 
$$
I need to show for that systen, that there is an unique solution in $(0,\infty)$ for any starting values $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. There is a hint: Show that suitable rectangles are invariant sets.

And I have no clue which rectangle or how to show invariance of the set.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: Did you try [plotting the phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx-x%5E3%2F3-y%2Cx-1-y%7D%2Cx%3D-5..5%2Cy%3D-5..5) first? (It can be sketched by hand too, looking at the nullclines and so on.) You'll need some kind of idea of what it looks like, otherwise it will be hard to figure out which rectangles might be worth trying.

Comment: @HansLundmark I have already did that and I have also determined the equilibria and proved thats asymptotically stable. But I just can't figure out which rectangular. Do you have any further tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an image of the phase portrait, with an idea that might get you started. The red curve is the $x$-nullcline and the orange line is the $y$-nullcline. Can you see that for a rectangle such as the one in the picture, sufficiently large and with its top-left and bottom-right cornes on the $x$-nullcline, the flow on the upper edge always has a downward component, the flow on the right edge always has a leftward component, and so on?

[image: annotated phase portrait]

Comment: Thank you very much, I think got the idea now. I will try to prove it later, but it should not be a big problem :-)